# Vue 3.0 component not applying classes from tailwind

Tags: vuejs3, vue-component, tailwind-css, web-frontend

The problem that I'm having is that want to use Tailwindcss to style my Vue components but it is not applying them. It is working for my views and `App.vue`, but somehow not for the components. I followed every step on the Vue Vite website and the Tailwindcss page for adding it to Vue.

This is what I have now:

`tailwind.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
    content: [
        './public/**/*.html',
        './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}',
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

`postcss.config.js`:

```js
export default {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
}
```

`main.js`:

```js
import './index.css'

import {createApp} from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(router)

app.mount('#app')
```

`index.css`:

```css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

`Article.vue`:

```js
<script setup>

defineProps(['title'])
</script>

<template>
  <div class="flex max-w-full flex-auto bg-teal-100 rounded-md p-8">{{ title }}</div>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

`App.vue`:

```js
<script setup>
import {RouterLink, RouterView} from 'vue-router'
</script>

<template>
  <header>
    <nav class="flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap bg-teal-500 p-6">
      <div class="flex items-center flex-shrink-0 text-white mr-6">
        <span class="font-semibold text-xl tracking-tight">Test Page</span>
      </div>
      <div class="block lg:hidden">
        <button
            class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 border rounded text-teal-200 border-teal-400 hover:text-white hover:border-white">
          <svg class="fill-current h-3 w-3" viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>Menu</title>
            <path d="M0 3h20v2H0V3zm0 6h20v2H0V9zm0 6h20v2H0v-2z"/>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="w-full block flex-grow lg:flex lg:items-center lg:w-auto">
        <div class="text-sm lg:flex-grow">
          <RouterLink class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-200 hover:text-white mr-4" to="/">Home
          </RouterLink>
          <RouterLink class="block mt-4 lg:inline-block lg:mt-0 text-teal-200 hover:text-white mr-4" to="/about">About
          </RouterLink>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <RouterView/>
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

`HomeView.vue`:

```js
<script setup xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
import Article from "@/components/Article.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <article>lol</article>
    <div class="bg-amber-500 w-max p-8 rounded-md">hi</div>
  </main>
</template>
```

Sorry if this question has been asked earlier, but after googling I found nothing. I've tried to add the components manually to `tailwind.config.js`. Also I tried importing Tailwindcss directly into the component. That didn't do the trick and also don't think that is the best way. I'm new to front-end frameworks and trying to learn for my study, but I'm stuck.

Public github: https://github.com/Develex/vue-test-1

Sorry if my English is not great, it is not my native language.

Comment: What styles are not being applied that you think should be? Seems to work as expected in [this StackBliz](https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/Develex/vue-test-1)

Comment: Somehow the tailwindcss style are being applied to the rest of the website, only not inside Article.vue are not being applied.
this part: 
`<template>
  <div class="flex max-w-full flex-auto bg-teal-100 rounded-md p-8">{{ title }}</div>
</template>`

Comment: How do I get that component to render? I can't find where you've used it.

Comment: I use the Article Component inside HomeView.vue, in the Main element

Comment: after some testing, the css is being applied to the Article component if I use it inside App.vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<article>` is a native HTML element, thus when `HomeView.vue` is rendered, it renders this native HTML element, not your `Article.vue` that you might expect:

[image]

Thus, no styling from your `Article.vue` component is observed.

To use your `Article` component, you'd need to match the casing of the component variable from the `import`, like:

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <Article title="lol"></Article>
    <div class="bg-amber-500 w-max p-8 rounded-md">hi</div>
  </main>
</template>
```

This will now *actually* render the `Article` component:

[image]

See this working in [this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so78114782?file=src%2Fviews%2FHomeView.vue)

Comment: thanks for the help. feel like a idiot now.